# Using key aliases in types/interfaces?

Tags: typescript

I am building an optimized database which serves key values as small as possible, and in my app I'd like to use them with the full name instead.

I used a function that returns LogAlias, which is basically Log but with their full length counterpart.

But is there a way to make it smarter ? Like telling the interface I want to use the alias over the actual key value ?

Here is what I am using right now:

```
What comes out of the database:
export type Log = {
  _id: string;
  date: string;
  uid: number;
  l: string;
  dn: string;
  m: string;
  c: string;
  b: Badges;
  bi: BadgeInfo;
  e: RawEmotes;
  si: SubInfo;
  d: number;
  j: string[];
  p: string[];
  mt: MessageType;
};

What I want to use in the app:
export type LogAlias = {
  messageId: string;
  date: string;
  userId: number;
  login: string;
  displayName: string;
  message: string;
  color: string;
  badges: Badges;
  badgeInfo: BadgeInfo;
  emotes: RawEmotes;
  subInfo: SubInfoAlias;
  duration: number;
  joined: string[];
  parted: string[];
  messageType: MessageType;
};
```

Thank you

NVH

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT solvable via pure types, as `types` from TypeScript exist only compile-time, and do NOT exist at runtime.

What you need is to describe the shape of the type you need, and then write a conversion function that takes the input object, and maps all the "ugly" props to their beautified counterparts in a new object that is returned in the end.

Doing it for multiple entities would suck, also will greatly increase the complexity of your codebase, so ... well, this is a question of importance and balancing it out.

There are some other ideas available, but those are even uglier than the above, while providing no clear benefit.

Comment: Thanks you! 
I will stick on using a conversion function then